# How do I avoid duplicate code for a function that uses an optional message parameter?

Tags: rust, string-formatting

I want to write my own assert function that can optionally have a message:

```
fn foo(msg: Option<&str>) {
    if let Some(m) = msg {
        panic!("{} - Something went wrong: {}", m, "additional info");
    } else {
        panic!("Something went wrong: {}", "additional info")
    }
}
```

How do I avoid duplicate code like that? How do I avoid multiple (re)allocations for the message strings?

Comment: Why would you worry about a single string allocation when panicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use empty strings when you don't print.

```
fn foo(msg: Option<&str>) {
    panic!("{}{}Something went wrong: {}", 
            { if let Some(m) = msg { m } else { "" } },
            { if let Some(_m) = msg { " - " } else { "" } },
            "additional info");
}
```

Which after rustfmt looks like this:

```
fn foo(msg: Option<&str>) {
    panic!(
        "{}{}Something went wrong: {}",
        {
            if let Some(m) = msg {
                m
            } else {
                ""
            }
        },
        {
            if let Some(_m) = msg {
                " - "
            } else {
                ""
            }
        },
        "additional info"
    );
}
```

Comment: There's a much better way of writing this. Notably, [the standard formatting for this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ea45fdd1593eb1a8256b8d648f89d34f) shows how unwieldy it is.

Comment: By "much better" you mean different indentation? Sure, I agree.

Comment: @Shepmaster curious what much better method you may suggest?

Comment: One possible way: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a29cb9c734a2ca58114bdad20f449a64

Comment: I wouldn't really do that, though – it sacrifices readability for the dubious benefit of saving a string allocation.

Comment: Usage of `unwrap_or` / `map_or` as @SvenMarnach posted is what I'd have done, modulo extracting variables.

Answer (score 4):

I often use a small wrapper like this:

```rust
struct OrEmptyS<T>(Option<T>);

impl<'a, T: std::fmt::Display> std::fmt::Display for OrEmptyS<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        if let Some(v) = &self.0 {
            v.fmt(f)
        } else {
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

// Extension trait to add methods on `Option`
trait OrEmpty<T> {
    fn or_empty(&self) -> OrEmptyS<&T>;
    fn empty_or<'a, U: ?Sized>(&'a self, alt: &'a U) -> OrEmptyS<&'a U>;
}

impl<T> OrEmpty<T> for Option<T> {
    fn or_empty(&self) -> OrEmptyS<&T> {
        OrEmptyS(self.as_ref())
    }

    fn empty_or<'a, U: ?Sized>(&'a self, alt: &'a U) -> OrEmptyS<&'a U> {
        OrEmptyS(self.as_ref().map(|_| alt))
    }
}
```

which you can use as

```rust
fn foo(msg: Option<&str>) {
    panic!(
        "{}{}Something went wrong: {}",
        msg.or_empty(),
        msg.empty_or(" - "),
        "additional info"
    );
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1535967df0bc3b2fce15e4ce7c74d63))